# CreateThread function parameter gets passed wrong

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

When I use the CreateThread function like so

```cpp
CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyModule::MyFunction, (LPVOID)&wsParam, 0, &dwThreadId);
```

The parameter's address gets passed wrongly, making the wstring (or any other type of parameter) invalid. The address simply doesn't point to the data that was passed.

The function that gets called as a new thread:

```cpp
std::wstring MyModule::MyFunction(LPVOID stringParam) {
    std::wstring wsParam = *reinterpret_cast<std::wstring*>(stringParam); //Bad alloc
}
```

Comment: Never cast the function pointer argument! Either it fits and works without a cast, or you're hiding a **serious** error.

Comment: It worked without casting it too, I just thought being explicit is a good practice

Comment: a c-style cast says "I dont care about any potential issues" very explicitly ;). Use a `static_cast` if you want to make some conversion into an explicit cast. If the `static_cast` does not work, then very likely the c-style cast was wrong too

Comment: Explicit casting is bad practice, it tells the compiler to shut up. If you need a cast then use it, but if you think you don't then don't, and let the compiler tell you if you are right or wrong.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. With the given info, the problem could be outside of the code shown as well.

Comment: The problem is not outside of the code shown, I posted this question with the answer your question checkbox ticked.

Comment: Why are you even using windows API when C++ has [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) (since C++11 !!) and lambda expressions for explicit modeling of what data you want to capture (and how : value or reference). Anything you can do without using the windows API do it without using the windows API

Comment: The callee's std::wstring return value requires space on the stack, reserved by the caller.  But that's not what CreateThread() knows, it assumes a function that returns a DWORD.  A value that doesn't require stack space.  Inevitably the callee's stack frame is off with parameter values at wrong addresses.  Do question the usefulness of returning an std::wstring, assuming it were possible, the caller would have to wait for the  thread to complete to obtain the result.  Making it pointless to use a thread, it might as well call the function directly.

Comment: Stackoverflow elitism nicely done. I've had trouble with using CreateThread which I am using because I have to for undiscussed reasons, but I get asked why I don't use X or Y instead? I've had my reason for it that's why I asked a question about CreateThread and not std::thread. Also this question was asked after I found the answer so I can share it with others having the same problem, but feel free to close the question, or even remove it please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer "To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together."

Nicely encouraged

Comment: @66Gramms sorry, this is not elitism. Your question is pretty unclear and so is your answer, that's all. And if they ask "why don't you use xyz", it's just suggestions, it might be relevant or not, nobody but you can know, take it or leave it. BTW the DVs are not mine.

Comment: Almost certainly the `wsParam` variable is being destructed before the thread procedure can read it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though it doesn't seem to be documented in the Windows API (or at least I didn't find it) the function being called for the new thread must return a `DWORD`.

Changing the called function's header to return a DWORD passes the parameter correctly.

```
DWORD MyModule::MyFunction(LPVOID stringParam) {
    std::wstring wsParam = *reinterpret_cast<std::wstring*>(stringParam); //Works now
}
```

Comment: Its documented very clearly. From the documentation of [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85): _lpStartAddress :
A pointer to the application-defined function to be executed by the thread. This pointer represents the starting address of the thread. For more information on the thread function, see [`ThreadProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85))_.

Comment: I was checking the documentation for the CreateThread function which didn't say anything on the matter. Thanks for the link! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread

Comment: Everything is in the dcocumentation. Read the documentation of  `CreateThread` closely, especially the description of the _lpStartAddress_ parameter.

Comment: Oh yeah I see now, my bad. It was a good learning experience, I'll be much more thorough with reading it in the future. Still I hope this post will help someone else in the future, encountering the same issue

Comment: Using `std::thread` will help avoid these sort of problems

Comment: BTW: With `void` instead of `DWORD`, the call to `CreateThread()` would not have compiled unless you put in an explicit cast, I'm sure. The cast is just a "shut up, compiler, I know what I'm doing", which was unfortunately not the case.

Comment: @66Gramms `MyFunction` doesn't do anything useful. and it's even wrong because it doesn't return anything. What's the deal?

Comment: std::thread is not related to the question. MyFunction is obviously not the function I use in the actual code, but it's the part that's relevant